# How to find repeated rows in pandas DataFrame for specific columns, and modify values by adding counter?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform, repeat

Consider a dataframe with 2 columns for easiness. The first column is `label` which has same values for some of the observations in dataset.

Sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
  
data = [('A', 28),
        ('B', 32),
        ('B', 32),
        ('C', 25),
        ('D', 25),
        ('D', 40),
        ('E', 32) ]

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['label', 'num'])
```

For column `label`, I want to find rows with similar values. And convert its value into `value_counter` like below:

```
label   num
A        28
B_1      32 
B_2      32
C        25
D_1      25
D_2      40
E        32
```

I tried to use pandas groupby but I don't know which `transform` I have to use.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
s = data_df.groupby('label').cumcount()+1
data_df['label'] = np.where(data_df.duplicated(subset='label',  keep=False),
                             data_df['label'] + '_' + s.astype(str), data_df['label'])
```

`OUTPUT`

```
  label  num
0     A   28
1   B_1   32
2   B_2   32
3     C   25
4   D_1   25
5   D_2   40
6     E   32
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty `dictionary`, which you can append with your label and it's count (`keys` and `values` respectively). Then depending on whether the label is new, or it exists, you can increment it's value or return it intact.

The last step would be to use this new `list` as a new label column:

```
labels = data_df['label'].tolist()
new_labels = []
label_c = {}

# iterate through your labels list
for val in labels:
    if val not in label_c:     # if label not the new label list
        label_c[val] = 0       # add it to dictionary
        new_labels.append(val) # add it to the output as is
    else:                      # if it's not new
        label_c[val] += 1      # increment its count
        new_labels.append(f"{val}_{label_c[val]}") # add it to the output along with its count

data_df['label'] = new_labels
```

prints back:

```
>>> print(data_df)

  label  num
0     A   28
1     B   32
2   B_1   32
3     C   25
4     D   25
5   D_1   40
6     E   32
```